# User with Owner Role in Google Cloud gets 403 when Using Gmail Api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-oauth

With `gcloud` I am logged into a terminal window with my email address, `me@gmail.com`. This project has the Gmail API enabled, and I am owner of this config. `gcloud auth list` shows

```
`Active Account`
`*me@gmail.com`
```

`gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT` shows that `me@gmail.com` as owner

I have an Oauth client/secret created in the project. My intent it to generate an access token to authenticate to the gmail API via the terminal with

```
`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels`. (me is my actual email address)
```

Doing so gives me a 403.  I can, however, use `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/`
and get a token with my particular scopes fine.  Do I need to pass the Oauth Client Id to print-access-token? Why wouldn't owner have permissions over all possible actions in an API that's enabled?

EDIT: I have tried logging with auth application-default credentials as well with the same result.

TIA

Comment: The command `print-access-token` does not include the required Gmail scopes when creating the access token. You will need to write code or use curl. The listing of scopes is here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes I wrote several articles on creating access tokens in curl and python on my site. Example: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the correct scope. You need to correctly scope your credential. Start by using this command to add the scope that you want in your credential

```
gcloud auth application-default login \
  --scopes='https://mail.google.com/',\
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
```

Then use the application-default access_token to call your service

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \ 
  https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels`. (me is my actual email address)
```

It should work better.

Comment: Makes total sense now.  I knew it had to be scope related, but glossed over the scopes parameter for application-default after i didn't see it on gcloud auth-print-access-token.  Grazie!